# What is Attachable really doing here?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, module, orchardcms

This code snippet from [Sipke's tutorial](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-4) (which is awesome, by the way) has me a little confused. In his tutorial, he says that .Attachable allows Content Parts to be added to Content Types. But in the code snippet, below a Content Part is declared as .Attachable(false) and is still being added to a Content Type. So there must be some other criteria that I'm not realizing. So what is really the difference between CustomerPart and the AddressPart, as far as Attachable is concerned?

```
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(typeof(Models.CustomerPart).Name, p => p
            .Attachable()
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Customer", t => t
            .WithPart(typeof(Models.CustomerPart).Name)
            .WithPart("UserPart")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(typeof(Models.AddressPart).Name, p => p
            .Attachable(false)
            .WithField("Name", f => f.OfType(typeof(TextField).Name))
            .WithField("AddressLine1", f => f.OfType(typeof(TextField).Name))
            .WithField("AddressLine2", f => f.OfType(typeof(TextField).Name))
            .WithField("Zipcode", f => f.OfType(typeof(TextField).Name))
            .WithField("City", f => f.OfType(typeof(TextField).Name))
            .WithField("Country", f => f.OfType(typeof(TextField).Name))
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Address", t => t
            .WithPart(typeof(Models.AddressPart).Name)
            );
```

Answer (score 4):

IIRC a content part can always be attached to a type (e.g. via an `ActivatingFilter<>`, or by specifying so in your migrations), however only parts who are marked as `Attachable()` will show up when you are building content types in the admin dashboard. So I think in this case the `CustomerPart` will appear when selecting content parts for a content type when constructing via the dashboard, whereas the `AddressPart` will not appear.

Edit: I've just ready though some of the walk through and I think the reasoning for this is because the `AddressPart` is only attached to an `Address` content item. There is a one to many relationship between customers and addresses, and it doesn't make sense to be able to allow the user to attach the `AddressPart` to other content types, so the `AddressPart` is hidden from users, but still attachable to content items from the migration.

Comment: That's correct: attachable is about what appears in the admin. A part that would not be attachable even in code would be useless anyway.